# OpenCL calling function from kernel-function - array elements are 0

Tags: arrays, function, opencl, d

I'm pretty new to OpenCL. My OpenCL-code is pretty simple. It contains 2 functions where the __kernel-functions calls another (non-kernel) function. I want pass the array to this function, but when I do that, my function (add) always returns 0. The complete array is 0.
But when I access the same index in my kernel-function, the result is as expected... here's the code I'm using:

```
    int add(__global  int * numArray) {
        return numArray[1]+numArray[2];

    }

    __kernel void sum(__global int * numArray, __global int * result) {
        result[get_global_id(0)] = numArray[0] //
        result[get_global_id(0)] = add(numArray); // = 0
    }
```

Is there anything I doing wrong here?

Comment: "The complete array is 0." Does this mean that all the elements of your array has the value 0?

Comment: My host generats random numbers which I'm passing to my kernel-function. When I access the numbers in my kernel-function, everything is fine. But when I pass the array to a helper function like add, all the elements of my array has the value 0.

Comment: Which OpenCL implementation you are using?

Comment: OpenCL 1.1 and library is cl4d (D programming language)

Comment: From what vendor is the implementation? 1.1 would imply nVidia.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon on this line:

```
result[get_global_id(0)] = numArray[0] //
```

Therefore the second line is just a continuation of the first (although I'd expect it to generate an error).

If that's not it, I'd change add() to use "numArray[0]" to do an exact comparison against the version that doesn't call add(), so you are comparing apples to apples (and not relying on the values in elements 1 and 2).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all... it was my mistake. I assigned some values to 0 and I just tried to add these.